# Installing reveal.js on Node

Tags: node.js, reveal.js

I'm trying to install reveal.js on Node so I can use the speaker notes locally.

I'm following the instructions without success: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#full-setup

I get these errors on the first step:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:235:25)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

Let me know if you need any more info. I installed Node v4.4.6 LTS.

Comment: which step exactly?

Comment: First step "$ git clone https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js.git"

Comment: Have you installed `git`? Also, you should only have `git clone github.com/hakimel/reveal.js.git` without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the instructions using Node.js version: v5.7.0 (npm version v3.8.1) without any issues.

I recommend installing `nvm` (https://github.com/creationix/nvm), so you can easily switch Node versions to resolve issues like this.

**Edit:**

Follow these instructions to install `git`, if you cannot clone the repository:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Make sure you don't copy the `$` when you paste the command in the instructions into your terminal.

Comment: They don't have a windows version. But I uninstalled node and installed v6.2.2 (includes npm 3.9.5). Same error in first step.

Comment: With git and using cmd I was able to clone the repository but when installing the npm I get so many warnings and errors... EDIT: but it might be working anyway, I'm doing some testes and I'll edit this later again.

Comment: So is your issue not with step one?

Comment: When I made the question the issue was with step one. After you advised me to install git and use it to clone the directory I was able to do it. But then step 4 and 5 had problems. Should I use the git or node for these two steps? (But I then tested and the speaker notes are working on the default site on the repository. But not in my website. I have to find what's the problem.)

Comment: `git` is a tool that lets you clone (download/copy) a repository (it can do a whole lot more, but this is what it is doing for your case). In step one, you are copying (cloning) the repository from GitHub to your local computer. Step 4/5 use `npm` which stands for "Node Package Manager." When you change directories into the cloned repository, you use `npm install` to install the software dependencies for reveal.js. Finally, `npm start` will start the server on http://localhost:8000 .

Comment: If the above comment wasn't enough, I suggest looking at some YouTube introductory videos to help wrap your mind around `git` and `node`/`npm`.

Comment: I meant to say that for the cloning step I used the cmd (after installing git) and when also using the cmd for steps four and five I get several warnings and errors. Is there any difference in running these steps on the node console? But thankfully the speaker notes work locally anyway.